# Where can I find a Baltoy in Pokémon Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Where I can find a Baltoy in Pokémon Moon? I need it for a GTS trade.

Answer (score 2):

Baltoy is not available in Moon, it is however available in Ultro Moon.

There it can be found in [Haina Desert](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Haina_Desert) during a [SOS Battle](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/SOS_Battle).

The only other way to get one in Generation VII is trading from another generation.